# Internet Explorer 11 installation fails with errorcode 9C59

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer-11

I get an error with installing IE11 on Windows 2008 R2

The final errorcode is:

```
Setup exit code: 0x00009C59 (40025)
```

The first reported error is:

```
'C:\Windows\SysNative\dism.exe .. exited with exit code 0x00000002 (2)
```

**The last lines from the log**

```
00:11.918: INFO:    Launched package installation: C:\Windows\SysNative\dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1E82C.tmp\IE11-neutral.Downloaded.cab /quiet /norestart
00:26.520: INFO:    Process 'C:\Windows\SysNative\dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1E82C.tmp\IE11-neutral.Downloaded.cab /quiet /norestart' exited with exit code 0x00000002 (2)
00:26.535: ERROR:   Neutral package installation failed (exit code = 0x00000002 (2)).
00:26.535: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiInstallDone(7), lParam=0x00009c59 returned 0x00000000.
00:26.535: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiStartFinish(11), lParam=0x00000000 returned 0x00000000.
00:26.567: INFO:    No reboot logic message NrApiFinish(12), lParam=0x00000000 returned 0x00000016.
00:26.567: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete.
00:26.567: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({89820200-ECBD-11cf-8B85-00AA005B4383})
00:31.574: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({89820200-ECBD-11cf-8B85-00AA005B4383})
00:36.582: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({89820200-ECBD-11cf-8B85-00AA005B4383})
00:41.589: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({89820200-ECBD-11cf-8B85-00AA005B4383})
00:46.597: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({89820200-ECBD-11cf-8B85-00AA005B4383})
00:51.605: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073})
00:56.612: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073})
01:01.620: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073})
01:06.628: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073})
01:11.635: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073})
01:16.643: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073})
01:21.650: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073})
01:26.658: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073})
01:31.666: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073})
01:36.673: INFO:    Waiting for Active Setup to complete. ({A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073})
01:41.806: INFO:    PauseOrResumeAUThread: Successfully resumed Automatic Updates.
02:30.884: INFO:    Setup exit code: 0x00009C59 (40025) - The neutral cab failed to install.
02:31.009: INFO:    Cleaning up temporary files in: C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1E82C.tmp
02:31.071: INFO:    Unable to remove directory C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1E82C.tmp, marking for deletion on reboot.
02:31.071: INFO:    Released Internet Explorer Installer Mutex
```

**What I tried already**

- [Microsofts' Troubleshooting a failed installation of Internet Explorer 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2872074/en-us)  didn't work
- System Update Readiness Tool ist installed
- Procmon didn't show the reason for the exit code 0x00000002 (2)

**My system**

- W2008 R2 SP1 on VMWare ESX 5.1
- Currently IE8 is installed

**EDIT**

This is the result of the System Update Readiness Tool

```
=================================
Checking System Update Readiness.
Binary Version 6.1.7601.22471
Package Version 26.0
2015-04-11 14:58

Checking Windows Servicing Packages

Checking Package Manifests and Catalogs

Checking Package Watchlist

Checking Component Watchlist

Checking Packages

Checking Component Store

Summary:
Seconds executed: 438
 No errors detected
(w) Unable to get system disk properties    0x0000045D  IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY    Disk Cache
```

Comment: did you get anywhere with this as I am getting very similar on several boxes we are trying to complete the upgrade on.

Comment: @TimAlexander sorry, no solution found, good luck!!

Comment: You might want to try the solution for a similar problem on Windows 7:  https://superuser.com/a/1211197/302402 .