# Windows update fails upon installation of IE11

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

So I was trying to get all updates installed in order to be eligible for win 10 upgrade, but when windows update tries to install ie11 it fails with 9C59 error code. Also manual installation of ie11 does not work saying a error has occured, try again. Searching microsoft knowledge base I did not find any solutions that worked.

Comment: _I did not find any solutions that worked._  We don't know what you've tried. So, editing your question with that info will avoid someone suggesting something that won't work.

Comment: [One possible answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321445.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You might have the problem that some previous installation or uninstallation process of IE did not work correctly and some packages of IE (9,10 or 11) are still installed on your system. You can manually uninstall all packages by running as administrator from cmd.exe:

```
FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows.
-InternetExplorer-*11.*.mum /c “cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart”

FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows.
-InternetExplorer-*10.*.mum /c “cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start
/w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart”

FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows.
-InternetExplorer-*9.*.mum /c “cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start
/w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart”
```

See also

- https://superuser.com/a/1199693
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2579295

After doing this your system should be clean and installation of IE11 should work again. If the installation still doesn't work, you might want to try the instructions given at

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-get-error-9c59-when-updating-internet-explorer/03d4473a-867b-44a5-9a37-913e9a5879cf
- https://jingyangli.wordpress.com/2015/08/18/ie11-install-problem-neutral-package-installation-failed-exit-code-0x00003715-14101-and-setup-exit-code-0x00009c59-40025/